# Android Retrofit2: Serialize null without GSON or JSONObject

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, json-deserialization, android-json

The result of API call in my Android app can be a JSON with configuration which is mapped to `SupportConfigurationJson` class, or just pure `null`. When I get a JSON, the app works properly, but when I get `null`, I get this exception:

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead
    JSON input: null
```

I should avoid using `GSON` in this project. I also found a solution, where API interface will return `Response<JSONObject>`, and after that my repository should check if this `JSONObject` is null and map it to `SupportConfigurationJson` if not. But in the project we always used responses with custom classes so I wonder, is there any other solution to get response with null or custom data class?

GettSupportConfiguration usecase class:

```
class GetSupportConfiguration @Inject constructor(
    private val supportConfigurationRepository: SupportConfigurationRepository
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(): Result<SupportConfiguration?> {
        return try {
            success(supportConfigurationRepository.getSupportConfiguration())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            /*
            THIS SOLUTION WORKED, BUT I DON'T THINK IT IS THE BEST WAY TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM
            if (e.message?.contains("JSON input: null") == true) {
                success(null)
            } else {
                failure(e)
            }
            */ 
                //I WAS USING THROW HERE TO SEE WHY THE APP ISN'T WORKING PROPERLY
            //throw(e)
            failure(e)
        }
    }
}
```

SupportConfigurationJson class:

```
@Serializable
data class SupportConfigurationJson(
    @SerialName("image_url")
    val imageUrl: String,
    @SerialName("description")
    val description: String,
    @SerialName("phone_number")
    val phoneNumber: String?,
    @SerialName("email")
    val email: String?
)
```

SupportConfigurationRepository class:

```
@Singleton
class SupportConfigurationRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: SupportConfigurationApi,
    private val jsonMapper: SupportConfigurationJsonMapper
) {

    suspend fun getSupportConfiguration(): SupportConfiguration? =
        mapJsonToSupportConfiguration(api.getSupportConfiguration().extractOrThrow())


    private suspend fun mapJsonToSupportConfiguration(
        supportConfiguration: SupportConfigurationJson?
    ) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        jsonMapper.mapToSupportSettings(supportConfiguration)
    }
}
```

```
fun <T> Response<T?>.extractOrThrow(): T? {
    val body = body()
    return if (isSuccessful) body else throw error()
}

fun <T> Response<T>.error(): Throwable {
    val statusCode = HttpStatusCode.from(code())
    val errorBody = errorBody()?.string()
    val cause = RuntimeException(errorBody ?: "Unknown error.")

    return when {
        statusCode.isClientError -> ClientError(statusCode, errorBody, cause)
        statusCode.isServerError -> ServerError(statusCode, errorBody, cause)
        else -> ResponseError(statusCode, errorBody, cause)
    }
}
```

SupportConfigurationApi class:

```
interface SupportConfigurationApi {

    @GET("/mobile_api/v1/support/configuration")
    suspend fun getSupportConfiguration(): Response<SupportConfigurationJson?>
}
```

SupportConfigurationJsonMapper class:

```
class SupportConfigurationJsonMapper @Inject constructor() {

    fun mapToSupportSettings(json: SupportConfigurationJson?): SupportConfiguration? {
        return if (json != null) {
            SupportConfiguration(
                email = json.email,
                phoneNumber = json.phoneNumber,
                description = json.description,
                imageUrl = Uri.parse(json.imageUrl)
            )
        } else null
    }
}
```

I create Retrofit like this:

```
@Provides
    @AuthorizedRetrofit
    fun provideAuthorizedRetrofit(
        @AuthorizedClient client: OkHttpClient,
        @BaseUrl baseUrl: String,
        converterFactory: Converter.Factory
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .build()
    }
```

```
@Provides
    @ExperimentalSerializationApi
    fun provideConverterFactory(json: Json): Converter.Factory {
        val mediaType = "application/json".toMediaType()
        return json.asConverterFactory(mediaType)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is explained [here](https://kenkyee.medium.com/retrofit2-doesnt-handle-empty-content-responses-bef2b33ee8ea) (1min read)
Api is supposed to return **"{}"** for **null**, If you can't change API add this converter to Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

You are interacting with your repository directly, i will suggest to use

> usecases

to interact with data layer.
Because you are not catching this exception over here, your app is crashing

```
suspend fun getSupportConfiguration(): SupportConfiguration? =
        mapJsonToSupportConfiguration(api.getSupportConfiguration().extractOrThrow())
```

Usecase usually catch these errors and show useful error msg at the ui.

Comment: Yes, I use usecase and catch errors in this class, but there isn't any important logic for the serialization process... but if this is in doubt, I will add it to description as well.